# Python default character encoding handling

Tags: python, character-encoding, utf

I've seen several post related to this, but no clear answer. Let's say I want to print the string `s=u'\xe9\xe1'` in a terminal which only supports ASCII (e.g., `LC_ALL=C; python3`). Is there any way to configure the following as default behaviour:

```
import sys
s = u'\xe9\xe1'
s = s.encode(sys.stdout.encoding, 'replace').decode(sys.stdout.encoding)
print(s)
```

I.e., I want to the string to print something - even garbage - rather than raising an exception (UnicodeEncodeError). I'm using python3.5.

I would like to avoid writing this for all of my strings which may contain UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one of three things:

- Adjust the error handler for `stdout` and `stderr` with the [`PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING):

  ```
  export PYTHONIOENCODING=:replace
  ```

  note the `:`; I didn't specify the codec, only the error handler.
- Replace the `stdout` `TextIOWrapper`, setting a different error handler:

  ```
  import sys
  import io

  sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(
      sys.stdout.buffer, encoding=sys.stdout.encoding, 
      errors='replace',
      line_buffering=sys.stdout.line_buffering)
  ```
- Create a separate `TextIOWrapper` instance around `sys.stdout.buffer` and pass that in as the `file` argument when printing:

  ```
  import sys
  import io

  replacing_stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(
      sys.stdout.buffer, encoding=sys.stdout.encoding, 
      errors='replace',
      line_buffering=sys.stdout.line_buffering)

  print(s, file=replacing_stdout)
  ```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - much appreciated! (I went with option 2)